# PDE Cauchy problem to Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, cauchy-problem

I have been given this question in polars and I tried but not sure if I did it right and if my solution is correct.

$$U_{rr}+\frac{1}{r^2}U_{\theta\theta} +\frac{1}{r}U_r=0$$
$$U(1,\theta)=1$$
$$U_r(1,\theta)=1$$

Initial conditons given means $U(1,\theta)=1$ and $U_\theta(1,\theta)=0$, 
$U_r(1,\theta)=1$.

Subtract both sides by $-\frac{1}{r^2}U_{\theta \theta}(1,\theta)$
$$U_{rr}(1,\theta)+\frac{1}{r}U_r(1,\theta)=-\frac{1}{r^2}U_{\theta \theta}(1,\theta)$$

$$ -r^2U_{rr}(1,\theta)-r=U_{\theta \theta}(1,\theta)$$

$$R =1$$

$$U_{\theta \theta}(1,\theta)=0$$

$$U_{rr}(1,\theta)=-1$$

So using Taylor series,
$$U(r,\theta)= u(1,0)+U_r(1,0)(r-1)......
=1+(r-1)-\frac{1}{2}(r-1)^2$$
And this was my full solution and the next terms are all zeroes so this is the actual solution as well I guess. Did I do this right? Any help will be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Well, if you plug it into the PDE do you get zero? It clearly satisfies the desired boundary conditions.

Comment: (You actually don't: the third term gives a $1/r$ that isn't compensated by anything else. So that can't be the full solution.)

Comment: what is the domain of the PDE?

Comment: Ok not a full solution maybe but is this correct so far?

Comment: There is no domain. All we have is the initial conditions. Does it looks right the way I did?

Comment: Are you sure? A unitary circle, may be... No your solution is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have basically taken the first few Taylor terms of the solution about $r=1$, but what you have does *not* satisfy the PDE elsewhere. Indeed:

$$\left ( \frac{d^2}{dr^2} + \frac{1}{r} \frac{d}{dr} \right ) \left ( 1 + (r-1) - \frac{1}{2} (r-1)^2 \right ) = -1 + \frac{1}{r} - \frac{r-1}{r}$$

which is not zero anywhere except $r=1$.

You might be able to continue using power series to solve the problem; the technical term for this procedure is the Frobenius method. But I doubt this is what your reference expects you to do. Notice that by the symmetry $U$ is really just a function of $r$, so you can look at the ODE problem

$$u''+u'/x=0,u(1)=1,u'(1)=1$$

which is actually not that hard to solve; consider substituting $v=u'$ to get started. (By the way, the method of solution of this ODE is closely related to writing the original PDE in divergence form...)

Comment: But we are supposed to only take the Taylor series of the first few terms. So then I didn't need to do this right.

Comment: @user486026 If that's what your reference said then sure...but I'm not sure why it would do that when the problem is easily solved explicitly. (You also didn't say that this was the requirement in the question. Also, in the correct solution even the very next term is nonzero...)

Answer (score 0):

$$\left\{
\begin{align}
&u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r^2}u_{\theta\theta} +\frac{1}{r}u_r=0\\ 
\\
&u(1,\theta)=1,\quad u_r(1,\theta)=1
\end{align}
\right.
$$
Let $r=\operatorname e^t$ so that for $u(r(t),\theta)$ we have
$u_t=u_r r_t$ and $u_{tt}=ru_r+r^2u_{rr}$. Thus the PDE becomes
$$
u_{tt}+u_{\theta\theta}=0
$$
By symmetry $u(t,\theta)=X(t)$.

So we have $u_{tt}=0$ and then $X(t)=at+b$ that is $u(r,\theta)=a\log r+b$.

From $u_r(1,\theta)=1=a$ and $u(1,\theta)=1=b$, we find

> $$
> u(r,\theta)=1+\log r\quad \text{for }r>0,\,\forall \theta
> $$

Comment: You didn't include $b$ in your final solution.

Comment: @Ian ops..it was a typo, corrected now. Thanks

Comment: Thanks! Hmm why we let r=e^t and then how we got log r?

Comment: @user486026 The substitution $r=e^t$ makes easier the PDE with $u(t, \theta)$ and at the end we must substitute back $t=\log r$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks and also can you please look at this as well please,     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2452152/pdes-existence-and-uniqueness-of-solutions