# PDEs existence and uniqueness of solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

So my question asks me to discuss the existence and uniqueness of solutions, finding all/any solutions.

Ut + UUx =1

Subject to

u(X,1)=2x

So here is what I did,

Write the pde as 
(u,1,1) (Ux,Ut,-1)=0

dx/dr =u ,     X(0)=s

dt/dr=1   ,   t(0)=1

du/dr=1   ,   u(0)=2s

Intgerating,
t=r+c -> t=r+1 as the intiial condition is t(0)=1

dx/dr=u = 2x given in the question and integrating this we get 
X=e^2r+C with c being s and we get X=e^(2r)+s

u = r+2s

Now using the jacobian,

(2e^(2r))(0)-(1)(1)=-1 but I should get 0 as we discussed in class. Any ideas where I might have made a mistake here?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
u_t+uu_x&=1\\
u(x,1)&=2x
\end{align}
\right.
$$
$$\left\{
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d t}{\mathrm d s}&=1 &t(0)&=1 &t(s)&=1+s\\
\frac{\mathrm d u}{\mathrm d s}&=1 &u(0)&=2\xi &u(s)&=2\xi+s\\
\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d s}&=u &x(0)&=\xi &x(s)&=\xi+2\xi s+\frac{s^2}{2}\\
\end{align}\right.
$$
We have $s=t-1$ and $\xi=\frac{x-\frac{s^2}{2}}{1+2s}$ and finally subsituting in $u(s)=2\xi+s$ we find
$$
u(x,t)=2\frac{x-\frac{(t-1)^2}{2}}{1+2(t-1)}+t-1=\frac{t^2-t+2x}{2t-1}
$$

Comment: Ok thanks just thinking why you took dx/ds instead of dx/dr and so on?

Comment: And for the jacobian we get 1+2s here. I think we should be getting 0 as we discussed in class.

Comment: $s$ is just an auxiliary variable...you can call it $r$ if you like..

Comment: Ok but do we need to calculate the jacobian here?